# Move objects to specified points in a scene?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have been trying to throw together a chess game using a 3dsmax model. At this point, I have been able to import the model, highlight the selected game piece I am interested in moving, and choose a square I want to move to. Here is a screenshot of the current state:

http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/9555/chessk.png

The black circle represents where I clicked, and you can see where the pawn went. I haven't done specific calculations on where it should go. Whenever I click on the board with a selected piece, it always moves in the same direction. It's because just threw in this dummy code to start off:

```
if ( isObjectSelected && isSquareSelected && moveObject )
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //PLACEHOLDER-DUMMY CODE
}

glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, pMaterial->triangleCount * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, model.getIndexBuffer() + pMaterial->startIndex );

if ( isObjectSelected && isSquareSelected )
    glPopMatrix();
```

What I was considering doing was after the model was done loading, is to somehow check which square on the board a game piece occupies. Then, when a piece is selected and a "move to" square is selected, find the x,y,z glTranslate3f to move to that center square.

Is this the best way? It seems as the game progresses, I will need to store the glTranslate of each piece individually. And when a piece goes from it's 2nd to 3rd spot, I should calculate the glTranslate from the original starting point to the 3rd spot, right?

But how would you figure out whether or not a game piece occupies a square, and how would you figure out glTranslate3f(X, Y, Z)  between two squares? Here is an example of a square from my .OBJ file

```
#
# object Square58
#

v  -37.1874 18.6313 80.7864
v  -67.0955 18.6313 91.4436
v  -56.4384 18.6313 121.3513
v  -26.5306 18.6313 110.6938
# 4 vertices

vn 0.0000 1.0000 -0.0000
# 1 vertex normals

vt 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
# 1 texture coords
```

I am assuming I would need to find the center of each square and say once the app knows this piece is in square1, and you clicked on sqaure4, calculate the translate & go. I am just not sure how to calculate the center of each square, and figure out what the translate coords should be from square1-->square4.

OR how I would determine which pieces occupies which square from the beginning. I can hard code this in during load, but it would help me more in understanding if there was a sound way to accomplish this.

Each square & game piece is a struct `GroupObject` like:

```
//A chess piece or square
struct GroupObject
{
    std::vector<Material *> materials;
    std::string             objectName;
    std::string             groupName;
    int                     index;
    std::vector<Vector3 *>  vertices;
    Vector3                 center;
};
```

And Vector3 looks like:

```
#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

#include <math.h>

class Vector3
{
public:
Vector3(float X = 0.0f, float Y = 0.0f, float Z = 0.0f)
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    z = Z;
}

Vector3 operator+=(const Vector3 &vec)
{
    return (*this = (*this + vec) );
}

Vector3 operator+(const Vector3 &vec)
{
    return Vector3(vec.x + x, vec.y + y, vec.z + z);
}

Vector3 operator-=(const Vector3 &vec)
{
    return (*this = (*this - vec) );
}

Vector3 operator-(const Vector3 &vec)
{
    return Vector3(x - vec.x, y - vec.y, z - vec.z);
}

Vector3 operator*=(float num)
{
    return (*this = (*this * num) );
}

Vector3 operator*(float num)
{
    return Vector3(x * num, y * num, z * num);
}

Vector3 operator/=(float num)
{
    return (*this = (*this / num) );
}

Vector3 operator/(float num)
{
    return Vector3(x / num, y / num, z / num);
}

Vector3 operator-(void)
{
    //invert direction of vector
    return Vector3(-x, -y, -z);
}

float Dot(Vector3 &vec)
{
    return (x * vec.x + y * vec.y + z * vec.z);
}

Vector3 operator*(const Vector3 &vec)
{
    //cross product
    return Vector3( y * vec.z - z * vec.y,
                    z * vec.x - x * vec.z,
                    x * vec.y - y * vec.x );
}

float Length(void)
{
    //length of vector
    return sqrt( x * x + y * y + z * z);
}

Vector3 Normalize(void)
{
    float length = Length();
    x /= length;
    y /= length;
    z /= length;

    return *this;
}

float Distance(Vector3 &vec)
{
    //find distance between two separate vectors
    float disX = vec.x - x;
    float disY = vec.y - y;
    float disZ = vec.z - z;

    return sqrt(disX * disX + disY * disY + disZ * disZ);
}

bool operator==(Vector3 &vec)
{
    return (vec.x == x && vec.y == y && vec.z == z);
}

bool operator!=(Vector3 &vec)
{
    return !(vec == *this);
}
```

public:
    float x, y, z;
};

```
#endif
```

I was going to use this to store the center of each square like:

Vector3 square->center = X, Y, Z

Hopefully this would help it determining where to move, and if something occupies that space, but figured I should get some help since I haven't done this before. I am also not sure how I should calculate it, or still completely clear on how to figure out whether a square has a game piece that occupies it at the beginning, or it's empty.

Any and all help is welcome. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Right now I had a buddy look in 3ds max and on a square object properties it said dimensions were x: 40.565 y: 40.565

Then I picked two squares, one in front of the other. I calculated the center of each by added all the vertices together and divided by the sum of the vertices. I got this:

```
#square 1
x: 111.12125
y: 18.631268
z: 78.286982

#square 2
x: 82.276817
y: 17.615297
z: 88.545845
```

But from my original example, the only way I could get even close to moving to the right spot was moving glTranslatef(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

The difference between the two centers listed above is much larger. I am doing something incorrect, but not seeing it.

Comment: You have your operator+= defined in terms of operator+.  That's backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[a-bit-offtopic]
When i was coding my univercity project, i used to draw my 'world' (which has something similar with check-desk: it is endless and have no colour distincts) using simple math formulas for determining each line cross points. When i got those points, i was able to simply determine which particular square cursor is pointing. To be honest, i used simple mathematics to determine those centers in the last ('production') version.

[Here](http://imm.io/3kdF) and [there](http:////imm.io/3kdG) are my old screens.

So, what's the trouble? When you're doing `glPushMatrix()`, your matrix resets to its defaults - the position becomes (0, 0, 0) and rotations are reset. If you wanna put your object in the point of intersect {line, plane}, where the line is the ray from camera origin through cursor position (recall camera theory in OpenGL: actually, screen is the plane in front of camera 'position' point) and the plane is something in front of that ray. **Note:** if you'll not define the plane - you'll be not able to determine intersection point.

Now, when you'll got intersection point, just do `glTranslatef(<intersection_point>)` and then draw your pawn or whatever.

If you are interested in pure code on how to determine intersection point - just notify me in comments.

Hope this will help.

**UPD:** here's the intersection point code i've mentioned before. It uses `sf::Vector3f` structure/class - it is taken from [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/) (i'm using it for all my GL projects to handle input events and forget 'bout window creation). You can define it as a simple structure with 3 floats. Function arguments are the mouse cursor' coordinates. Calling this would provide you with intersection point coordinates.

```
sf::Vector3f ScreenToSpace(int x, int y)
{
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
    GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    winX = (float) x;
    winY = (float) viewport[3] - (float) y;
    glReadPixels(x, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

    gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);

    return sf::Vector3f((float) posX, (float) posY, (float) posZ);
}
```

Here's the example on how you should use this (as far as i've understood your problem):

```
sf::Vector3f v = ScreenToSpace(App.GetInput().GetMouseX(), App.GetInput().GetMouseY()); // get global coordinates
v = SpaceToDeskCorrection(v.x, v.y, v.z); // align v to the check-desk cell center

glPushMatrix(); // reset matrix state (incl. position and rotation) and save previous one
  glTranslatef(v.x, v.y, v.z); // set matrix position to the intersection point
  DrawPawn(); // well, you'll understand this line, right? =)
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The entire board is an object in itself, so I could make that the plane I am guessing. But yes, it would help me A LOT if you had code to determine the intersection point(s). I am still very shaky in openGL

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am going to try this when I get back to my computer and will report back!

Comment: Okay. I think, you can create position correction function by determining board borders widths and/or cells centers using this function as helper one. But also, you could draw desk as i've done it in my univercity project and then just append something like borders using vertex and index arrays. If so, you'll be able to scale your chess =)

Comment: I will download the SFML library and take a look at the SpaceToDeskCorrection as well. I got an X,Y,Z back from ScreenToSpace that would launch the pawn way out of view. Thanks

Comment: I like SFML. It's just simple and have all the features i need and nothing useless. You should try it. Really.

Comment: I am already using SDL. I am going to try and plugin SFML as well tomorrow. I also think I need to draw this out. I seem to be making it harder than it is.

Comment: I added a link to the full project at the bottom of the original post. Can't seem to find anything about SpaceToDeskCorrection on SFML.

Comment: Although, I realized after I wrote that comment, that I need to write my own SpaceToDeskCorrection. ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault. I forgot to mention this yesterday. I apologise.

Comment: @Hallik, comment on your source code: don't you think it would be much more pretty if your glPushMatrix(), model translate/draw and glPopMatrix were inside one `if` block?

Comment: Yes, but at this point I am trying to figure out how to scale the glTranslatef properly. If I can't, I am going to try writing a SpaceToDeskCorrection method. Any suggestions?

Comment: On how to write this function? Sure if so: find out centers of each cell on your desk (or figure out how to calculate it mathematically - that's not so hard) and then decide where should chess figure stand, depending on intersection point coords. E.g.: i've selected point (x0, y0) which corresponds to (a, b) on the desk.  SpaceToDeskCorrection(x0, y0) should return (a, b) cell center coordinates. And if i move cursor to the (x1, y1) (for ex. a little left-downwards from (x0, y0) but still within the same cell) point, it should return the same coords as (x0, y0) given.

Comment: It's frustrating because I am getting absolute world coords from each square->center, and the difference between the starting & ending square is a number like 100 times larger than glTranslatef is expecting. Blargh

Comment: Strange... Wrong calculations?

Comment: I sum each X,Y,Z vertices and divide by the # of vertices. Look at the method that starts at line 1010 here: https://github.com/nbyloff/KinectChess/blob/master/KinectChess/ModelOBJ.cpp

Comment: Errrmmm... Strange way to find out centers of cells... Or even board center... I recommend you to draw board manually, using vertex arrays and formulas (pseudo-ruby-code): `for (rows) { |t| for (columns) { |i| x[i+1] = x[i] + CellSize; y[i+1] = y[t]; } y[t+1] = y[t] + CellSize }`

Comment: I am already using glDrawElements for speed. Not sure if I should break that up again. I think I going to use your SFML, and if I can't get that working quick, just switch to ogre3d. Very frustrating, tempted to take the easy way out :)

Comment: Sigh.... /me does not like OGRE for its complicated structure in some places (for example, if i wanna make the hole in the wall i would not be able to do it simply) and its model format. But it is a great solution if you are not needed in such rare functionality =)

Comment: I am going to try SFML first. And read a bit more. There is something REALLY fishy with glTranslatef expecting small x,y,z values, but the distance between two squares being so large. It's come down to a math problem I can't figure out. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently done a checkers game myself, 2D but the same principles apply. First of all I would suggest you keep an array with board squares, which as you defined in your struct has a centre var.

To know where each piece is, you could for instance add a variable which is a pointer to a given square, or simply a representation like 'E4' or 'A8' (square code). Having this, you would automatically have the x,y coordinates of where the piece is, and once detecting which square you want to move it to, you just substitute the pointer to the new piece and get its centre information, which is where you want to translate the piece to. This also has the added benefit that it makes it easier for you to check later when a piece takes over another one from the adversary, or simply if it can move to a certain square (go through all the pieces, if any of them is laying on the square you want to go to, don't allow the move).

To find out the centre of any square, assuming you don't know it when you create the board (don't you ?), and do an average over all the constituting vertices x and y coordinates (if the board is laying on the xy plane). For instance, Square58 centre = (v1(x)+v2(x)+v3(x)+v4(x) ; v1(y)+v2(y)+v3(y)+v4(y)).

I hope that was clear enough, if not just let me know what you didn't get and I'll try to explain.

EDIT: Sorry, I wrote something wrong. In the Square58 centre.... line, you divide the final sum by 4 (to get the average).. ie:

Square58 centre = ((v1(x)+v2(x)+v3(x)+v4(x))/4 ; (v1(y)+v2(y)+v3(y)+v4(y))/4).

Comment: I will calculate the center of each square as you have shown. Once I do that, would my glTranslate3f be currentSquare(x,y,z) - squareToMoveTo(x,y,z)? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing you do 1 glTranslation per piece per new game state. In that case, you just need to do glTranslate with the new square's centre. You don't keep track of all previous positions, just the newest one. Say, before rendering the scene every piece is at 0,0,0. You then apply glTranslate to each piece with it's centre's coordinates (which will be the new square once u move it)

Comment: I got the center of each square, and I tried a glTranslate(x, y, 0.0f); to it's new position, but ti still sent the object way outside the board. I am going to try calculating the distance between the start->center & end->center and see what happens. Then I am going to try the suggestion below to use SFML